# How to select relevant parameters

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

I have a large set of data corresponding to parameters used or (not used) to determine the value of many indicators.These indicators are also used to to determine a value type.

For example:

parameter/indicator

```
                        | Comfort | VacancyRate | AirQuality | FireSecurity
city                    |    x    |             |     x      |      x
number of rooms         |    x    |      x      |            |
nb of fire extinguishers|         |             |            |      x
```

city impacts the comfort, air quality and fire security

and indicator/value type

```
            | ContextualValue | GreenValue | FinancialValue
Comfort     |       x         |     x      |       x
VacancyRate |                 |            |       x
AirQuality  |                 |     x      |       x
```

Comfort impacts the contextualValue the greenValue and the financialValue

I have thousands of parameters, several hundred indicators and five value types.

I was wondering if there was any way to determine the real use of a parameter  and indicator using statistics or maybe machine learning; the objective is to filter out any "useless" data. "20% of data corresponding to 80% of the necessary information."
 Any advice would be helpful !

Elliott

Comment: This is too broad to be answerable here. It sounds like you need to take a few courses in machine learning. FWIW, the topic of your question is [tag:feature-selection]. This has been discussed many times on the site, so you could search around & read through the existing material.

Comment: I already took a few courses on ML with Coursera, implemented a "simple" algorithm, played around with some python libs and then with Spark ML from the Hadoop environment. Since machine learning can do a great many things i was curious to see if it was possible to use it in this case. Arman answered though, PCA is the way to go.

Comment: It's unlikely PCA alone will give the best results for such data, because it "knows" nothing about which variables you want to predict and which ones you will be using for the prediction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think best approach here is [dimensionality reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction) , it does exactly what you wants , it transforms your set of features to another space , and in that space some of your features are useless , so they will be removed , the must known method here is [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis), you can have your 20% of feature while output 80 % accuracy model prediction .

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your quick answer with links! I'll give it a look and mark as answer as soon as it's done

Comment: PCA corresponds exactly to what i'm looking for. now just need to create an algorithm to analyse the data and get the required output